# How to model data enrichment pipeline in a type safe way while reducing allocations

Tags: c#, generics, casting, immutability, allocation

I have a pipeline of operations written in C#, where items can be enriched with new information progressively.
At each step of the pipeline, I want the typing to make it clear, which fields have been enriched : if the field exists, then it's not null, and it won't be changed further in the pipeline.

This is a possible modelization:

```
public class Info {
  public int a {get;}
}

public interface Item {
  ItemWithInfo EnrichWithInfo(int a);
}

public interface ItemWithInfo {
  Info {get;}
}
```

Implementation of Item mutates itself and returns itself when EnrichWithInfo is called.
This looks clean to me:

- no allocation
- other parts of the code only see the interfaces and don't see implementation mutates itself.

Yet, I'm manipulating lists of Item, and this is what happens when calling ToItemWithInfo:

```
List<Item> items;
List<ItemWithInfo> itemsWithInfo = new List<ItemWithInfo>(items.Count());
foreach(var item in items) {
  itemsWithInfo.Add(item.ToItemWithInfo(...));
}
```

I have to allocate a new list wereas I could work with the same.

Maybe I can do that but I feel it's a bit more ugly:

```
foreach(var item in items) {
  item.ToItemWithInfo(...);
}
IEnumerable<ItemWithInfo> itemsWithInfo = items.Cast<ItemWithInfo>();
```

Is there a way to reduce allocations while keeping the code clean ?

Comment: You are only allocating one new object here: a `List<ItemWithInfo>`. The items it references are the same instances that are referenced by `items`, so I can't see any issue here. As for a "cleaner" way of doing this, `Enumerable.Select` would be more concise: `var itemsWithInfo = items.Select(item => item.ToItemWithInfo(...));`.

Comment: hmmm creation of List<ItemWithInfo> creates a new array of references if I'm not wrong ? For the Select I don't really agree, as it will create an enumerable, and ToItemWithInfo will be called again whenever enumerable is scanned, no ?